Implicitly choose array element type and size from indirect template parameter
I have a class and depending on the value of a template parameter, I'd like to change the element type and size of an array.
The below obviously doesn't compile but I am using it to show what I would like to do.
struct A {};
struct B {};

template <size_t N>
class C 
{
    // This is illegal syntax, just using it as pseudo-code
    if constexpr(N <= 5) 
    {
        std::array<A, 20> _array;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::array<B, 80> _array;    
    }
};

(N is not the size of the array)
I know I could pass A and 20 as two more template parameters, but is there a way to avoid doing this?

Please do not edit posts to change what you perceive is better syntax.

Do something along these lines:
#include <type_traits>

template<size_t N> class C {
    typedef std::array<A,20> First;
    typedef std::array<B,80> Second;
    typename std::conditional<N<=5, First, Second>::type _array;
    // C++14 and later lets you to do this:
    // std::conditional_t<N<=5, First, Second> _array;
};


Or perhaps using First = std::array<A,20>; using Second = std::array<B,80>;

is typename keyword needed on the last line ?

@M.M pfft... possibly, yes. This is one of things I just add if/when the compiler complains. Or rather, I'd use  conditional_t in most cases anyway since I don't have to bother with C++11... but I'll add it just to be sure. Thanks!

Cribbing off Christian Stieber's answer, but modifying to put all of the computation in the template parameters. N is the only template parameter that needs to be provided, but the others can be which may make this more flexible.
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<
    std::size_t N, 
    typename F = std::array<A, 20>, 
    typename S = std::array<B, 80>,
    typename T = typename std::conditional<N <= 5, F, S>::type
> 
class C {
    T _array;
};

On godbolt.
